# How to deal with this toxic client?

Tags: clients

I will give some context to this situation, which is starting to affect me quite a lot.

I started in this company around 9 months ago. My first project was helping one guy with a web portal that was the main priority at the moment. Time went on and the result was cool.

All these months went on and my coworker left, but I still managed to take control successfully of the projects.

One month ago or a month and a half, after the client from that first project was afk for months, they come back to continue the development process. I went back to that portal happily since it was the most ambitious one we have and I liked how it was going on.

But things very quickly started to get very ugly.

My company is very small, around 10/11 programmers. All lead by the development lead and then there is the owner itself. All of them are wonderful coworkers in the personal aspect, and in the technical side I cannot comment on a lot of them since I don't work with them on the same projects.

The dev lead starting telling us that this first client was complaining (first time it happened to me since I started). The dev lead and the owner of my company knew we were working in a nice path and it was just business as usual, if that makes sense. Anyways I continued with my work as usual.

Slowly but steady, this client started to call the owner of the company stating that a lot of features where failing or not developed (they had been afk for months and haven't seen anything). This escalated to a point where we all had to have a meeting in which the client and it's workers requested a more agile experience (which I agree on, since I prefer the closer communication). A coworker and me installed Slack and started communicating daily with them. All of this while they started making production use of the half-ended portal, due to pressure from their bosses or something like that. I had to do extra-hours to meet the daily new deadlines. My boss, the owner, thank me and all of that but I was feeling pretty stressed.

These people (The client, which is comprised of a boss and 2 or 3 workers) act incredibly toxic. They are always in a passive-aggresive mood, mocking our code quality and development organization (which I don't dissagree with, we do have our fair share of errors), but all of this while being pretty disrespecful. They talk like a 15 year old bully, with phrases like 'OMG how is it possible for you to not have done x feature before xd".

One of the workers is more educated, but sometimes also falls in that line, which makes me think that their boss is actually encouraging them to behave like this to put pressure on us. This more educated worker is now on vacation and they have left in charge one of the worst people I've seen in a work environment.

Today we had the first day with him. All day long he has been mocking and complaining about us etc etc etc. I had to make a lot of effort to not tell him to **** off.

This project hasn't been well organized, both parties included. We tend to say yes to their requests almost all the time, and I don't like how we are managing this project. I also have my share of errors too, I don't want to look like I do not acknowledge that. But this is almost crossing a line and I am starting to get frustrated and really affected by this. The project is, mostly, behind on schedule. The design is cool, and most of the problems are due to not proper testing (which makes us lose time) and uncompleted features that somehow we failed to communicate properly to this client. I can help change some of that, but it is impossible to me to change the whole company (I even have problems with convincing some of my coworkers to use git properly instead of downloading files from our server and then reuploading them).

Every day I have to deal with the client which is basically throwing at me all their frustration and being very disrespectful.

I know my boss knows that their claims about how bad everything is are not realistic and he typically "sides with me" but he still likes to claim that we will fix everything really quickly. All of this while the client changes deadlines everyday and comes up with different news, like one of their clients starting to use the platform/web in 5 days without proper warning and starting to complain because something is not like in a production environment.

Anyways, how do you think I should proceed? My goal here is to make this situation improve, I don't necessarily need to step aside from the project if the personal treatment gets good again.

Comment: Nothing scream less agile that wanting to control how the team must do things and insulting them

Comment: It is a weird thing. I do recognize that my company is very far away from an agile environment, so I understand they demand more of that, but what is really happening is that I spend 50% of my time answering their rant.

Comment: Just a little question - what does 'afk' mean?

Answer (score 12):

You need to go to your manager and say that the client has a unprofessional behavior toward you, the team and the company and ask help in how to handle the situation. Ideally I would ask to revert to proxy communication, that is no direct communication between the client and you but all communication need to pass by a proxy (Product owner or proxy product owner if you want agile terminology). You can argue that it will allow you to be more focus on your task and delivery instead of having to manage the client.

Comment: I honestly do not understand why someone would ever think that losing respect is going to help things get faster and better. It seems some people do.

Comment: @S.Dre Sounds like your boss still thinks money is more important than your working experience. I like the answer of JayZ. Put an internal product owner between you and the client. the po can focus on the getting the specs and you focus on developing. If your boss doesn't agree with this i think that says enough how much he truly cares

Answer (score 2):

> stating that a lot of features where failing or not developed

This is almost always:

1. Specs were bad.  The customer wants it to do something other than the requirements.  Or,
2. Code delivered wrong.  Document your unit tests prior to delivery.  Then very rarely,
3. Interacts poorly with a different feature once you get to SIT.

If you don't have a robust process to manage requirements and delivery, customers get mad.  Some customers are just bad.  My experience is that the ones that treat you/us badly treat their own employees badly so that's all they know.  Don't complain about how they talk to you, deliver the product like you need to so they have nothing to complain about.

Comment: I honestly think they behave the same between them. I would love to deliver the project in-time as it should though I sadly believe it is out of reach with my capacities (I am a junior and this should be handled by one or two seniors)

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to your boss. Have him look at the money side: How much money is the company making, and at what effort? And factor in that if this continues, you will be leaving sooner than later? And the guy replacing you will leave as well? Once a client has been trained to shout and demand and get everything, this is hard to recover from except by firing the client.

As the boss, I would think that finding a new client is a much more effective way to drive my business forward. The best way forward would be if you have some managerial type (doesn't have to be a manager, just act as one), who will be the sole contact with this toxic client and stops his toxic behaviour. If the client complains to the boss, the boss doesn't make promises but passes him to this manager. If the client complains to you, the same. Just need someone who can say "No" and mean it.

Comment: Fortunately, my boss is someone with whom is easy to talk to. It is a big project though, let's see if reverting to proxy com, like @JayZ says, works firstly, and if not, I will think on your approach. At the end I just try to be respectful above all.

Comment: @S.Dre It is not that your boss is "easy to talk with" - he needs to be able to CONTROL the situation and from what you say he does not.